# Install tcpdump on windows host container node

Tags: windows, tcpdump

I have a windows host machine to which I will connect through command line

This is a windows container worker node machine where I can connect only through Command Line and no GUI

How could I install TCPDUMP from commandline. Only way I know is to install through GUI but here I dont have that way to connect.

Any other alternatives to resolve this ?